# Airflow failed version command

Tags: python, airflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    operators._integrate_plugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/operators/__init__.py", line 104, in _integrate_plugins
    from airflow.plugins_manager import operators_modules, register_inbuilt_operator_links
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/plugins_manager.py", line 194, in <module>
    plugins
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/plugins_manager.py", line 104, in load_entrypoint_plugins
    plugin_obj = entry_point.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2460, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2483, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 791, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (tzlocal 2.1 (/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('tzlocal<2.0.0,>=1.4'), {'apache-airflow'})
```

****airflow was installed by colleagues from work, I first went to the server and the first thing I did was try to check its version**

As far as I understand the problem may be due to two installed pythons-2.7 and 3.6 or because of the tzlocal version - but I don't know what it is**

the oddity is that the web muzzle raised by colleagues seems to work normally )) but commands from the console give me this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `tzlocal` package version 2.1 but `apache-airflow` requires `tzlocal` with version 1.4-2.0.0.
Downgrade your `tzlocal` to version 2.0.0:

```
pip install -Iv tzlocal==2.0.0
```

Note that if you have other software which uses `tzlocal` you may break it if it's not compatible with version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip freeze|grep tzlocal    
tzlocal==1.5.1
```

self solved